# Prevent regeneration of S3 pre-signed URLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, amazon-s3, meteor

I have an attachment functionality on my app. Users can upload Documents to S3 using Slingshot and then click a button which opens up a modal and a carousel displaying the attachments.

The downloadUrls from S3 are stored in Mongo and I have a template helper to spit them out and then an `each` puts them into the carousel. This all works pretty fluidly actually.

However, I want to use signed urls for better security. My issue is that clicking the button to display the modal actually creates a subtemplate each time. This subtemplate then calls a Method to create and return the signed urls. This isn't efficient.

Ideally, I'd like for the modal and carousel to remain reactive. So that a user can upload a new document and then see it without refreshing the page. But - at the same time, I don't want to resign a bunch of the documents again.

I was taking the route of using a Session Var and then diffing between urls to see if they've changed or not. But this doesn't seem right. I must note, that the browser does cache these uploads in the carousel (they're mostly images). So i don't particularly care too much about the actual signed url's expirate time.

Any ideas? I've read some patterns on using timefreeze to predate signed urls..so that you only recreate if it's been > than the expiration date. However, this pattern would still make the call to the md server side and still execute the s3.getSignedUrl fn..

Thanks!

Comment: Would be easier to make recommendations if we saw the code you have right now. Modal usually are not re-created but just hide and show. Or do you want this to stay between sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the modal apart of the parent template. Then - I used a local collection instead of Sessions. On Modal.shown, I simply check the length of the local collection, if it doesn't exist then I make the server call to get the signed urls. This should guarantee it gets called once.

New S3 files then can just get inserted into this new local collection. This all makes things work reactively.

Cleanest soln I have atm